# VBA - flickering after xlsheetvisible = true

Tags: excel, vba

I've got a problem and really need some help from you. I was trying to google the solution, but found nothing useful. My macro runs by clicking on a commandbutton1 which is located on sheet1. Important detail: a chart is also located on sheet1.

The only thing the macro does is switching sheet2 from 'hidden' to 'visible'.

```
Sub abc()

    Sheets(2).Visible = Not Sheets(2).Visible

End Sub
```

**THE PROBLEM: after switching the sheet2 from hidden to visible the screen is flickering.**

Notes:

1. The problem occurs only on the sheets with charts. It seems like excel is doing some chart update.
2. It occurs only when sheet2 is being switched to "visible".
3. I've tried:

```
   Application.EnableEvents = False
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
   Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
```

4. I deleted any other macros and events in the workbook.
5. I've tried to run a macro directly from VBA editor (not via commandbutton1).
6. I've tried debugging step by step.

---

Is there anyone who can help me with this issue?

Comment: The settings for the `Visible` property are Longs (xlSheetVisible (-1), xlSheetHidden (0), XlSheetVeryHidden (2)). Your use of boolean values shouldn't work just fine, and it does, but I wonder if the toggle somehow enables a double-switch in the way it's called. The flicker may indicate that a sheet is briefly activated. So I wonder whether Sheets(2) is a ChartSheet and where the data for the chart are located. Is there a PivotSheet that might feel its services are called upon at that moment? Have you tried removing the chart?

Comment: The macro is as simple as possible and it works. It works the same even if I set 'xlSheetVisible' and 'xlSheetHidden' properties in the conditional instruction. The screen flickering always appears. Yeah, I suspected that Excel is briefly activating other sheet, but on the sheets with no charts there is no flickering. So it's probably chart-related issue. The problem exists no matter where the data to the chart is located. The sheet2 is a standard worksheet. No PivotSheet (whatever it is) in the workbook. The thing is not to remove the chart, but to remove the flickering.

Comment: My point is whether it's the sheet with the data that is being activated. If data and chart are on the same sheet, then which sheet might be activated. And if there is no candidate then the flicker can't be caused by another sheet being activated. If no other sheet is activated, then what is causing the flicker? A chart being refreshed doesn't cause a flicker. With this kind of thoughts you end up looking at errors in the registry or Excel. Can you try your worksheet on another machine?

Comment: I haven't tried it on a different machine. It would be great if you could run the macro on your own machine with clean new workbook and let me know your results.
TIP: Add a chart with NO DATA attached to it (just a blank chart).

Comment: I started with a worksheet with a chart in it, no data, being the active sheet and ran your macro from the Developer tab > Macros > [abc] > Run. No flicker. The next sheet became active. From there I ran abc again by the same method. No flicker. Then I repeated the test with the next sheet hidden. Forth and back: no flicker.

Comment: After few runs it flickers. Not every time though. Always while switching sheet2 to visible.

Comment: I switched 10 times, activating sheets in between. Steady as a rock. If you have truly excluded all action by your code the only remaining possible culprit must be the machine - or the chart. That's why I suggested deleting the chart: to separate the sheet from the chart. Perhaps it turns out to be the sheet and not the chart. Try it with another chart. Perhaps it's that particular chart.

Comment: Has anyone seen the issue I mentioned on his computer?